# Referencing a local file within npm package

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

How do we reference local files within npm package? Since the npm package is installed by another consumer, would these references become obsolete with respect to the root folder of consumer?

For example, I have created a npm package for angular. This package also reships few html and css files from a third party(They do not have angular packages). I made sure the files are copied to `...dist\thirdparty` during package publish. I would like to reference some of these files within my npm package using relative path or other mechanisms.

E.g

```
@Component({
selector: 'ng2-my-library',
template: '<div></div>'
})
export class MyLibraryComponent {
.....
var newWindowUrl = "./thirdparty/some.html"; **// Need to relatively locate some.html here**
window.open(newWindowUrl);
.....
}
```

After I install `my-package` to a sample angular application, the above code results in `"localhost:3000/thirdparty/some.html"`, which is inaccurate.

How do I do this?

After installing my package, the consumer will have this structure
`consumerApp
  node_modules(Folder)
    ng2-my-library(Folder)
      ng2-pdfjs-viewer.umd.js // This is where I need to access some.html
      thirdparty(Folder)
        some.html`

I also considered instructing consumers of the package to do something like this, but this instruction is quite dependant on other build tools to copy or redirect to the html, which is not what I want.

```
   var TransferWebpackPlugin = require('transfer-webpack-plugin');
         ...
         plugins: [
           new TransferWebpackPlugin([
             { from: 'node_modules/my-package/assets', to: path.join(__dirname, 'my/public') }
           ])
         ]
```

I also tried to use this package. Apparently it did not provide me proper results for html.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-reference

Comment: What the expected behavior you are looking for?

Comment: As I stated, simply put, while authoring an angular library, what is the best mechanism to reference a static html "within the library". When the library is installed by the consumer, the static html will be installed under ./node_modules/thirdparty/some.html.

Comment: The component needs to know its root path, if the component is mounted by 2 different modules at 2 different paths then how would it work? You can use `window.location.href` as such but I doubt that would help.

Comment: Can you show your package file structure as it is when installed in `node_modules`? I'm a little confused as to where this third party stuff is getting installed and where your stuff is getting installed

Comment: I have added the folder structure when the package is installed into a consumer application

Comment: The application with angular-cli will build the bundle with all the dependencies that you import, styles, html, svg, img, etc. You can launch `ng build` and see the result in the `./dist` directory. If you want to know more about that process you can go to the webpack documentation.

Comment: You could try exposing publicly in your webserver the `thirdparty` folder and reference it like `window.open('/thirdparty/some.html')` in your component?

Comment: @David. I thought about instructing consumer of my package to either, manually copy `thirdparty` folder to their assets or other public folders or instructing them to use `TransferWebpackPlugin`. As I stated in the question, the basic intent is to have no extra steps other than importing the library in app-module after the consumer runs `npm install ng2-my-library`. The package should be self sufficient and should install/configure its static assets properly and should be able to access them webserver/build/pack tool agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `__dirname` instead `.` to get the local directory which the file is saved in. Change your code to:

```
var newWindowUrl = __dirname + "/thirdparty/some.html";
window.open(newWindowUrl);
```

More information about __dirname [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname).

Don't forget to include node types in your project:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node
```

Comment: This made the url in the new window resolved to (On consumer of package) : `http://thirdparty/some.html` which is inaccurate. Please see my additional info in the question about the web-pack

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

1 - make the assets public

Make static assets accessible from your webserver (i.e. the `thirdparty` folder)

For instance, if you are using express, you could use the [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) package

```
var path = require('path');
var assetsFolder = path.join(__dirname, './node_modules/ng2-my-library/thirdparty');

app.use('/thirdparty', express.static(assetsFolder));
//...
app.listen ...
```

2 - reference the file

In your package's component, reference the file like this

```
window.open('/thirdparty/some.html')
```

For instance, if you are using express, you can just

**Edit**

You could also copy the files with a npm post install task, but you still need to have them copied where the browser can serve them statically. You cannot be sure that all clients will have an `assets` folder for instance. So I think there will always be some kind of webserver configuration needed somehow

Comment: Unfortunately I do not use express

Comment: The  principle is the same whatever the webserver. Which one do you use?

Comment: I am building a library, I prefer not to include instructions for copying or redirecting to html for different server technologies or webpack plugin configurations to client users. My library should be webserver agnostic as I am referring to an html file inside my npm package itself from within my component.

Comment: @int-i imho since you want to serve a static file, it does depend on the webserver which means you need to configure it somehow. Even if you have a npm post install task copying the files somewhere, the webserver needs to be aware of it to configure the rules properly (even if assets are copied in root directory). That may work for assets folder only if you are sure that all users will have that assets folder in the same place

Comment: This is what I felt from my research. I still believed there would be a way to embed the html using a build step(web pack for example) and thus getting it served as an when required. If you look at this npm package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-reference, it is successful for css files and quite does solve a similar problem(Not working with html though)

Comment: In case if you would like to test with my library, here it is : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdfjs-viewer. Install instructions are available in the page. The client application can be a simple angular2+ application (ng new...)

Comment: Though I am still seeking what is needed to be done to bind/embed html inside my package, our discussion yielded some insight into how this cannot be achieved. Hence I am awarding the bounty which would expire today

Comment: @int-i Thanks for that. Post an update if you do find another way, but I honestly don't think there is one